# Handling inconsistent record delimeters in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, flat-file

I have a "fun" flat file I need to import. It's mostly fixed width with every record consisting of 516 characters, except the last record is only 514 and when importing as fixed width it skips that last record because of the missing 2 characters. (FYI there is no useful data in the final characters of each record so I don't even include them in the FF source).

The final characters are a record delimiter which would enable ragged right, except for two hiccups. First, the delimiter is usually "B", which can be problematic given we have things like names, addresses, and emails in the record. Secondly, I said it's usually "B", but sometimes it's inexplicably a double quotation mark. Simple example below, each record is 22 but the last is only 20

```
'George    Bush      B Berry     Goldwater B Silver    Surfer    " Mork      Mindy     '
```

How would you handle importing this? As a possible work around, can you add two spaces to the last line of the incoming flat file source data without modifying the actual file?

Comment: Sounds like it's the generation of the file that needs fixing, not the import process.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately that is not an option. It's some legacy software without source code that is still being used.

Comment: So these are being extracted using different processes?

Comment: It's how the legacy software stores data from one session to the next/across users. Hence why my workaround suggestion specified not actually modifying the file, as doing so will cause the legacy software to crash.

Comment: So a user can perform the *same* actions and get a *different* delimiter?

Comment: i'd probably just write a manual parser for this monstrosity

Comment: Thom A as far as I'm aware, yes. I'm sure there has to be something in the legacy software that dictates what delimiter to use, but I can't see any pattern or relevant quality in each record.

Comment: Blargh, perhaps it's time you just got everything out of that legacy system and then never looked back. As it's legacy then it's not like things are going to change any more. Then you don't have to deal with the fact that the same actions produce different results anymore.

Comment: Been trying to move to SAP for a while now. It's a process. Unfortunately we still need things in the mean time.

Comment: Moving to SAP to solve your legacy software issues is like bombing for peace etc

Comment: I suggest adding a separate file-fixup step that runs before the SSIS import. It could be as simple as a PowerShell script that reads the file as a single string, checks the length for a multiple of 22, appends a few extra characters as needed, and writes the result.

Comment: T N can't modify the file or it will crash the legacy software.

Comment: You can create a copy of the file with fixed structure

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... Normalize your delimiters.

This assumes your source file does not exceed 2GB.

`[NewVal]` can be parsed as necessary

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'George    Bush      B Berry     Goldwater B Silver    Surfer    " Mork      Mindy     '

Select NewVal = trim(Value)
      ,Seq    = ordinal
 From  string_split(replace(replace(@S,' B ','|'),' " ','|'),'|',1)
```

Or another OPTION if truly fixed width

```
Select NewVal = substring(@S,n*22,20)
      ,Seq    = N+1
 From (Select Top 5000 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By 1/0) From master..spt_values n1 )  A
 Where N<=len(@S)/22
```

**Results**

```
NewVal               Seq
George    Bush       1
Berry     Goldwater  2
Silver    Surfer     3
Mork      Mindy      4
```

I should add... to Import your source file

```
Declare @S varchar(max); 
Select @S = BulkColumn FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\working\testdata.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) x;
```